# オプションメニューの内容を動的に変更する(Kotlin)

Tags: android, java, kotlin

オプションメニューの内容を動的に変更したいのですが、MenuItemのインスタンス作成時にエラーが出ます。
[参考サイト](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/zakkiver24+rororossa/20110316/1300285365)

var item = MenuItem()

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

kotlinの場合、参考サイトと同じようにできるのでしょうか？

[こちらにも同じ質問をしていますTeratail](https://teratail.com/questions/20346)

Comment: MenuItemはインターフェースなので、当然コンストラクタもありません。MenuInflaterを利用してみてください。

Comment: MenuInflaterはsetVisibleメソッドを持っていません

Comment: この質問内容は他サイトにマルチポストされていると思いますが、質問本文にマルチポストである旨と、できればURLを記載して頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

正攻法としては、Kotlin文法を学びJavaコードと対応付けられるようにする、ということになると思いますが、マルチポスト先ではそのよう指向されているようなので別の邪道を。

KotlinでAndroid開発を行っているということはおそらくAndroid Studio上で開発していると思われますが、[JavaからKotlinへの変換機能](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html#converting-java-code-to-kotlin)があります。
Javaコードが既に存在しているのであれば、その機能で自動変換してやればそれなりのKotlinコードが得られます。

今回の場合、適当にダミーの`Activity`クラスを新規作成し、そのファイルに該当メソッドをペーストした後、上記の機能を使用すると次のように変換されます。

```
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    // メニューアイテムを取得

    if (flag === 0) {
        // menu0を表示
        menu.findItem(R.id.item0).setVisible(true)
        // menu1を非表示
        menu.findItem(R.id.item1).setVisible(false)
    } else if (flag === 1) {
        // menu0を非表示
        menu.findItem(R.id.item0).setVisible(false)
        // menu1を表示
        menu.findItem(R.id.item1).setVisible(true)
    }
    return true
}
```